# How to Distribute a program in java over multiple machines?

Tags: java, distributed-computing

I have written a code in java that works over a large data. I want to distribute this to multiple machines to work on parts of data and to get the processing done more quickly. I have never worked on Distributed Computing before. Are there tools to get this done? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a [hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) cluster

Comment: I would make sure you are processing the data as efficiently as possible and that IO is not a bottleneck. Multiple machines provides more CPU and memory but can make IO bottlenecks worse.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I believe IO is not a problem in my case. It is the processing that takes a lot of time. That's why I want to distribute it.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gridgain](http://www.gridgain.org) works fairly well. [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) is a great one but needs more dev. [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com) coulb be a good outsider

I can cite others too, but it's difficult to answer your question without knowing what types of datas and processing are involved. Are processes I/O intensive or CPU-Bound ?

One of the question is "How big your dataset is ?".

Comment: Thanks. I was just reading about Hadoop, trying to find a how to guide.I need to find intersections between every pair of dataset.So,even a relatively big data takes a lot of time.

Comment: We use Gridgain in Production since 3 years now, and we have found it very versatile and easy to use. It is very performant for CPU-intensive task

Comment: Thanks @Grooveek..It seems to be what I was looking for..but for now I can't download it completely (for some reason it always stops at 75mb). I will try it as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

seems like you want to do a [map-reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) algorithem.

[Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) is an open source project that provides a framework to do exactly that.